# Import xml2js in angular4 application

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm having problems using xml2js in my Angular4 Application.

I installed it via npm, and imported it like this:

```
import {parseString} from "xml2js";
```

But when I start my application, I get this error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/node_modules/xml2js
```

I also install typings.

I'm new to Angular (and Typescript), so i would be glad if someone could help me and explain what I did wrong :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I imported the library exactly as you did with a clean project created using the angular cli and it imports and works fine.

If you are new to angular I would recommend using the official cli tool for setting up your project, it simplifies a lot of things related to importing packages.

https://cli.angular.io/

Answer (score 0):

```
import * as xml2js from 'xml2js';
```

or

```
import { parseString } from 'xml2js';
```

If don't work, need run

> npm install --save @types/xml2js